# Missed calls log not showing in Lenovo A7000

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, call-history, lenovo, missed-calls

My mobile is Lenovo A7000 with Android lolipop 
Recently I the missed call logs not showing, sometimes for one or the other number it shows, it might be stored contact or new but the log is not happening, I also cleared the logs and cleared cache memory of call logs, but not fixed.
I tried updating firmware too but no use.
Please suggest me, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Today I was checking my phone for call log but didn't find anything, but after while I open securezone from statusbar on home screen all call logs are visible. So turn on secure zone.

Comment: Considering that you have not mentioned your device and this "securezone" feature is not a core Android feature but is device-specific, I'm flagging this post for deletion as it may confuse other people who need a legitimate solution.